# border in button html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a border in a button, I tried to create 2 div and then do `display: inline-block` but it doesn't work, here is my code:

```css
`#vid {
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  border: #ffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

#h5-vid {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #ffff;
  border-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button id="vid"><p>Videos</p><div id="h5-vid"><h5 id="h5-text-vid">New!</h5></button></div>`
```

This is what I want to get:

[image]

This is what I got:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBm9B.png]

Comment: Your html code is not correct.

Comment: @SatoTakeru how can i fix it?

Comment: I will try it first. And let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Put both elements with text inside the button:

```
<button id="vid">
  <p>Videos</p>
  <h5 id="h5-text-vid">NEW</h5>
</button>
```

Use `display: flex;` with justify and align center for the button then simply add border to the `h5` element using `border: solid 1px black;`

Here is a working snippet:

```css
#vid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 4px;
  width: 95px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  border: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#h5-text-vid {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 6pt;
  font-weight: 800;
}

body {
  /* Just for demo */
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<button id="vid">
  <p>Videos</p>
  <h5 id="h5-text-vid">NEW</h5>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work because `p` tag is `block` element.
And also `p` and `h5` tag has `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end`.
So I removed those margins, and set `display: inline-block` to `p` tag.
Now, it works.

**Note:** You set `border-color` to `div#h5-vid`, but didn't work because div doesn't have `border` in default.
So I changed it as `border: 1px solid black`.

```css
p, h5 {
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#vid{
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

#h5-vid{
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<button id="vid"><p>Videos</p><div id="h5-vid"><h5 id="h5-text-vid">New!</h5></div></button>
```